# "Can PHP inheritence behave like JS inheritance?" - Why was this question closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256454/how-can-an-instance-of-a-subclass-inherit-the-properties-of-a-specific-instance

The question was basically, "how can I make PHP inheritance pretend like it's Javascript inheritance, at least as far as properties are concerned?"

I came across this question via a Google search (because I was trying to do the same thing) and found the question and the OP's answer quite useful.  Was this an "earlier edit" story or am I missing something about what makes a legitimate question?

Comment: Probably because [Stack Overflow is not a code translation service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129362/140505).

Comment: @Oded, Did you read the question?  This is not a "make my js script work in php" question. It's a straightforward question about implementing instance based inheritance in a language that doesn't do it automatically.

Comment: It was closed by five ordinary users in November 2011. Finding out why they all voted to close will be well nigh impossible.

Comment: @ChrisF, isn't the whole point of having a detailed meta site and FAQs/rules that the unique properties of the question cause it to be closed transparently and reproducibly?  If it's dependent on the inscrutable whims of a handful of arbitrary users, then we're much less advanced than I thought we were.

Comment: The questions isn't very clear. 1. *inherit* is used wrongfully. 2. It's basically: This is my code. How can I change *PHP* so my code does want I want it to?

Comment: @mmdanziger - yes, but you'd need to contact the 5 users who voted to close and see if they could remember why they voted the way they did 6 months later. I know I wouldn't remember.

Comment: @Dennis, thank you for addressing the content of the question.  Though poorly phrased, the question is not really ambiguous.  And the question class of "I'm trying to do something that my language doesn't really do--how can I force it?" is vast, answerable and exceedingly useful to have answers for.  So I don't see why that would disqualify it.

Comment: @mmdanziger: I didn't understand the question *at all* before reading the self-answer the OP provided. All he wanted to do was access the parent object, and he should have told so in his question. Looks like more people agreed that the question was bad, since is has been deleted now.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at profiles <sup>more on that below</sup> of five users who voted to close, I see that their score in [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag is 7k, 349, 886, 2K, and 282 respectively.

- <sub>Score is the number of upvotes minus downotes they've got for asking and answering PHP questions.</sub>

Everyone of those who voted to close has at least one badge in php tag, totally they've got 5 bronze badges, 3 silver ones and 2 golden.

- <sub>Tag badges are awarded as a recognition of certain achievement in answering, eg golden badge [means](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/93/php)</sub>

  > <sub>Earned 1000 upvotes for at least 200 answers in php tag.</sub>

For comparison, asker of the question has php tag score 36 and no badges in this tag.

Taking above into account, I think <s>how dare you ask?</s> that most likely, you're missing something about what makes a legitimate question in php tag.

---

*Looking at profiles of users who voted to close* - these are displayed in closed questions like at below screen shot:

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9nlr.jpg]

Comment: @Timjadarnel27 thanks! I tested that and you're indeed right. I wiped out the "privileges stuff" off the answer